# unable to read file for file handling, using boost library to obtain file path

Tags: c++, boost

```
ifstream my_file;
for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("F:/mails"); dir != end; ++dir) {
    if (dir->path().extension() != ".txt")
      continue;                                                        

    std::cout << *dir << "\n";                                         
    std::cout << dir->path().filename() << "\n";                        
    my_file.open(*dir);
    //rest of the code
 }
```

When I try to open .txt file using the above method compiler gives the following

```
error at "my_file.open(*dir);"... maybe some casting issue.
error C2664: 'void std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::open(const char *,std::ios_base::open_mode)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'boost::filesystem::directory_entry' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

Answer (score 2):

[std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) accepts only `const char*` as pathname argument (and `std::string` since C++11). So you should convert path objects to string's using `c_str()` or `native()` [methods](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path):

```
for (boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir("F:/mails");
     dir != end; ++dir
) {
    if (dir->path().extension() != ".txt")
        continue;
    ...
    my_file.open(dir->path.c_str()); // or better dir->path.native(), but this requires C++11
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to this

```
my_file.open(boost::filesystem::canonical(*dir).string());
```